# how to define Franklin Gothic font for svg

Tags: svg, fonts

I have an svg file that was generated from an Adobe Illustrator vector image. The text is supposed to be from the Franklin Gothic family:

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73.9063 529.8633)" font-family="'FranklinGothic-BookCnd'" font-size="8.2637">2</text>
```

While all looks fine in Illustrator, when I view the svg file in a web browser (Chrome and Firefox), the font looks like Arial, I guess. How do I make browsers render the text in the Franklin Gothic font?

Comment: First you'd have to license it, e.g. from [Fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/franklin-gothic)

Comment: @StephenThomas: So it's not a default?

Comment: Not on Macs, iPhones, iPads, most Android devices, or most Linux distributions

Comment: @StephenThomas: But it's not rendering correctly on windows.

Comment: Can't help with that.

Comment: you need to load the font into the browser for use by your SVG (using some @font-face CSS), and you need to be legally allowed to do so. You are using a custom font, so you'll need to serve that font along with the SVG.